# Effect of error parameter to solution of the system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have $A, B$, and $L$ and their relation is shown as pictured below. suppose $A, B$, and $L$ are all known, but $L$ has an error in each element. How does this error affect to solution of this equation system in two cases $n=6$ and $n>6$? I'm new in math so if my description is not clear, please tell me. Thanks, a lot!!!

[image: equations system here]

Comment: In general, the degree to which errors may propagate throughout your problem depends on the solution method. Are you using normal equations? QR decomposition? Some are more robust to errors than others.